# Unable to get data between multiple keyword using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

My powershell script doesn't seems to work to extract the data between multiple keywords spread across various lines.
I want to select all the lines after NAME1 till NAME2..6 appears.So all the data between NAME1 & NAME2/3/4/5/6. The keyword NAME1 appears in the file multiple times so does other keywords. The regex however works but i am unable to figure out the mistake or the approach that i am taking when i use the regex in powershell script.

`(Get-Content .\withoutStar.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '(?is)(?<=\NAME1\b).*?(?=\bNAME2\b|\bNAME3\b|NAME4|NAME5|NAME6\b)'}) | Set-Content .\AllfunctionGroup.txt`

The sample data and regex can be tested here.[Sample data and regex](https://regex101.com/r/HiieCr/2/)

Can anyone throw light on this what is missing in my script.

Comment: I think that with trying to match multiple lines it may be easier to use something like a for loop so you can match on a line and keep adding each line or match to a variable until your code logic tells it to stop.

Comment: What kind of output would you like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your script is here :
`Where-Object {$_ -match '(?is)(?<=\bNAME1\b).*?(?=\bNAME2\b|\bNAME3\b|NAME4|NAME5|NAME6\b)'}`
This doesn't mean "keep the matches", but "if there is a match, keep the entire string".

Here is another way to do what you want :

```
$text = Get-Content .\withoutStar.txt
$regex = "(?is)(?<=\bNAME1\b).*?(?=\bNAME[2-6]\b)"
Set-Content .\AllfunctionGroup.txt -Value ""
(Select-String -Pattern $regex -Input $text -AllMatches).Matches | ForEach {
    Add-Content .\AllfunctionGroup.txt $_.Value
}
```

**Edit :** I simplified a bit your regex