# Powershell question - How can I deleted lines from a certain position?

Tags: powershell, search, design-patterns, line, select-string

(Sorry in advance for my bad english.)

I have 2 questions:

1. Question:
   I have a .txt file and search with powershell for a word into the .txt:

My code:
`Select-String .\example.txt -pattern "myword" | select -ExpandProperty line`

OK nice. PowerShell found the word within line 63.
After line 63, the .txt file has x more lines, and all of (64) them should be deleted.
How can this be done?

`get-content .\example.txt | select-string -pattern 'myword' -notmatch | Out-File .\new_example.txt`

This deleted only line 63. However, this should remain and only the rest should be deleted.

2. Question:
   Almost the same. I search for two countings
   Example: 12 and 33 into the .txt
   Powershell found not 12a and 33a.
   That's right. Powershell  should for it "11a until 56a", and clear line "10a" and "123a"

Example .txt file:
10a,
11a,
21a,
20w,
32a,
56a,
123a,

That is desired .txt file:
11a,
21a,
20w,
32a,
56a,

How can I make it? I hope so mutch that you can help me by this problems.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the proposed prototype in [`#15136` Add `-From` and `-To` parameters to `Select-String`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136):

```
@'
One
Two
myword
three
'@ -split '\r?\n' |SelectString -To myword
```

returns

```
One
Two
```

---

```
'10a', '11a', '21a', '20w', '32a', '56a', '123a' |
    SelectString -From '(?=11a)' -To '(?<=56a)'
```

Returns

```
11a
21a
20w
32a
56a
```

See also:

- [Extract specific text and extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886161/extract-specific-text-and-extract)
- [How to select between multiple lines in power shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393884/how-to-select-between-multiple-lines-in-power-shell)
- [How to read lines between 2 special characters in txt-file with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611180/how-to-read-lines-between-2-special-characters-in-txt-file-with-powershell)
- [Unable to get data between multiple keyword using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615089/unable-to-get-data-between-multiple-keyword-using-powershell)
- [Need Regex to match multiple lines until Match is found between common delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178732/need-regex-to-match-multiple-lines-until-match-is-found-between-common-delimiter?r=SearchResults)
- [Extract multiple lines of text between two key words from shell command in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890978/extract-multiple-lines-of-text-between-two-key-words-from-shell-command-in-power)
- [Extract block of text using regex and powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952978/extract-block-of-text-using-regex-and-powershell)
- [Need to search a line from a long config file with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270218/need-to-search-a-line-from-a-long-config-file-with-powershell)
- [Powershell Regex: Reading a multi-line string between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942804/powershell-regex-reading-a-multi-line-string-between-two-points?r=SearchResults)
- [regex select multilines in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086165/regex-select-multilines-in-powershell)