# regex select multilines in powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I created a file like this

```
echo "test 1", Hello, foo, bar, world, "test 2" > test.txt
```

and the result is this:

```
test 1
Hello
foo
bar
a better world
test 2
```

I need to remove all the text starting with the keyword "Hello" and ending with "world", including both keywords.

Something like this

```
test 1
test 2
```

I tried

```
$pattern='(?s)(?<=/Hello/\r?\n).*?(?=world)'
(Get-Content -Path .\test.txt -Raw) -replace $pattern, "" | Set-Content -Path .\test.txt
```

but nothing happend.
What can I try?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I mean that I know the last part of the line ("world") and not the entire line ("a better world")

Comment: Remove the `/`'s: `(?s)(?<=Hello\r?\n).*?(?=world)` (PowerShell isn't javascript ;-) )

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the result is test 1 Hello world test2 but I need to remove also Hello world

Comment: it seems like you could do it with `-replace '(?s)\s*Hello.*world'`

Comment: @Leo Your post say "the text _between_ the keywords", please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75086165/edit) to reflect what you actually want

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, my since-deleted answer wouldn't have deleted `Hello` and `world`, but Santiago's solution is much simpler

Comment: Nicely done, @Santiago - I suggest posting that as an answer (the only consideration worth mentioning is whether the `.*` should be greedy or not).

Comment: @mklement0 Are you sure? https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/e55p1rV56o1H.png?o=1

Comment: thanks @mklement0 but im honestly still unclear on what OP wants

Comment: @mklement0 I guess you can undelete your answer (which most certainly removes the keywords too) :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, sorry, I got confused: yes, my answer removes the keywords, because I believe that to be the OP's intent ("including both keywords").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the starting and ending keywords you could use either [`(?s)\s*Hello.*world`](https://regex101.com/r/o1xD6U/1) or [`(?s)\s*Hello.*?world`](https://regex101.com/r/4ACgFr/1) depending on if you want `.*` to be *greedy* or *lazy*.

```bash
(Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)\s*Hello.*world' |
    Set-Content path\to\result.txt
```

Use [`-creplace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-regular-expressions) for case sensitive matching of the keywords.

Comment: I also like the `-NoNewLine` option after the `Set-Content` command, just to avoid the new empty line at the end of the file

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside that there are extraneous `/` in your regex, reformulate it as follows:<sup>Tip of the hat to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).</sup>

```
$pattern = '(?sm)^Hello\r?\n.*?world\r?\n'

(Get-Content -Path .\test.txt -Raw) -replace $pattern | 
  Set-Content -Path .\test.txt
```

This removes the line starting with `Hello` all the way through the (first) subsequent line that ends in `world`, including the next newline.
This yields the desired output, as shown in your question.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Aside from the extraneous `/` chars., **your primary problem is that you are using *look-around assertions* (`(?<=...)`, `(?=...)`)**, which cause what they match *not* to be captured as part of the overall match, and are therefore *not* replaced by `-replace`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate with [How can I deleted lines from a certain position?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169550/1701026) or any of the included other duplicates:

```
'test1', 'Hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'world', 'test2' |SelectString -From '(?=Hello)' -To '(?<=world)'
```

Comment: Note that you're doing line-by-line processing, whereas the OP's attempt uses single-string, multi-line processing. I'm sure there are plenty of posts here that are variations of the same theme, though the specifics often warrant separate answers. Your custom `SelectString` function is a nice alternative approach, but, given that its name looks like `Select-String`, I suggest making it clear (here too) that a custom function is being used.